# Is there any way or command to do the double reset of the esp8266 through CODE(sketch)?

Tags: esp8266

I just want to do the double reset of the ESP8266 through code (sketch) .Is there any command or function for this ?is it possible??

Comment: Double reset? What's that?

Comment: Why would you want to? If the device is already under your control, couldn’t you just run the code you would otherwise run after a double reset (like reconfiguring Wifi)?

Comment: you have an esp8266 module wired to Arduino and you want to reset it from the sketch in Arduino?

Comment: In node mcu we have one double reset button .when we press that button it will re start the wifi .

Comment: yes sir ,how do i go for that???@Juraj

Comment: I think we are all confused with the term you are using: "double reset button".  We have no idea what you are talking about as none of us use this term.  If all you want is to restart the WIFI, look at any code that uses the WIFI radio and study how it starts the WIFI radio.  Chances are if you run that code again the WIFI radio will be re-initialized.

Comment: Of course then there is [this project at github](https://github.com/datacute/DoubleResetDetector).

Comment: @kiran, there is no "double reset button". There is a procedure that involves pressing reset twice, which tells the NodeMCU to enter Wifi reconfiguration mode (or whatever), but only if it's configured to detect a double reset and act on it. If you want to generate a double reset programatically, I presume you could also just run the piece of code that you'd run upon detecting a (manually generated) double reset.

Comment: wire a pin of Arduino to reset pin of the esp8266. in setup set the pin as INPUT. if you want to reset the esp8266, set the pin as OUTPUT, then write it LOW, then set it again as INPUT. don't write it HIGH. for double reset repeat the reset.

Answer (score 0):

There are not enough details in the question so we need to guess the goal of the project.  Assuming the goal is to have alternative behaviors depending on pressing the reset button once or twice with in a given span of time.

[This project at github](https://github.com/datacute/DoubleResetDetector) likely uses the RTC and some of the RTC flash memory in an ESP8266 to determine if the reset button has been pressed once or twice in a given span of time.

From that project:

> PURPOSE: Detects a double reset so that an alternative start-up mode
> can be used. One example use is to allow re-configuration of a
> device's wifi.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is about *generating* a double reset programatically, not detecting it.

Comment: I am not sure generating a double reset (what ever this turns out to be) is the end goal.  Let us hear a response from the person (@kiran) posting the question.  I had hoped he would respond to this answer and by doing so would give us enough information to make a better question and answer.

Comment: I agree. The question and the underlying reasons for it are far from clear.